# how do i count words of an String input if i have already counted letters and numbers using Charact method, also count characters i have com this far?

Tags: java

```java
package Shak;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lesseon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println(str.length());
        int charc = 0;
        int numbers = 0;
        int alphabets = 0;
        int words = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))) {
                alphabets++;

            }
            if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
                numbers++;

            }
            str.split("\\s++"); //trying to split to remove the white space and then `your text`count the characters 
            if (str.length()<0) {
                charc= (alphabets+numbers)-str.length();
            }
            else {

            }

        }

        System.out.println(alphabets);
        System.out.println(numbers);
        System.out.println(charc);
    }

}
```

I thought spliting would remove the white spaces and then i coud use my alphabet counter and number together minus the lenght and would get the odd characters, i have no idea how to count the words

Comment: I fixed your example code formatting. In the future, either indent all lines by 4 spaces, *or* wrap in a pair of triple back-ticks.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `str.split(` inside your `for` loop, you are needlessly splitting the entire string over and over again. This is awkward.

First [split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) on spaces.

```
String[] words = input.split( " " ) ;
int countWords = words.length ;
```

Loop that array to do your analysis. Start by [stripping](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()) away [whitespace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(int)).

```
for( String word : words ) 
{
    String w = word.strip() ;
    …
}
```

To work with individual characters, avoid `char`. That 16-bit value is physically incapable of representing most characters. Instead, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

For each word, get the code point integers assigned by the Unicode Consortium to each of the characters in your string.

```
int[] codePoints = w.codePoints().toArray();
```

Loop those code points. Ask if the code point is a digit or a letter. If neither, let's count that too.

```java
{
    if ( Character.isLetter( codePoint ) ) { countLetters++; }
    else if ( Character.isDigit( codePoint ) ) { countDigits++; }
    else countOther++ ;
}
```

Pull all that code together.

```java
package work.basil.example.text;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Words
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Words app = new Words();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        String input = "Testing, testing, 1, 2, 3.";

        String[] words = input.split( " " );
        int countWords = words.length;
        System.out.println( "Arrays.toString( words ) = " + Arrays.toString( words ) );

        int countLetters = 0;
        int countDigits = 0;
        int countOther = 0;  // Punctuation, etc.
        for ( String word : words )
        {
            String w = word.strip();
            int[] codePoints = w.codePoints().toArray();
            for ( int codePoint : codePoints )
            {
                if ( Character.isLetter( codePoint ) ) { countLetters++; }
                else if ( Character.isDigit( codePoint ) ) { countDigits++; }
                else { countOther++; }
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "countWords = " + countWords );
        System.out.println( "countLetters = " + countLetters );
        System.out.println( "countDigits = " + countDigits );
        System.out.println( "countOther = " + countOther );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
Arrays.toString( words ) = [Testing,, testing,, 1,, 2,, 3.]
countWords = 5
countLetters = 14
countDigits = 3
countOther = 5
```

Comment: ok but it counts 1 the nimbers as a word wich they are not ?

Comment: @gone4-1000 So modify the code to count how many of the `w` strings have only letters and no digits.